# My app crashing as I try to pass data from one activity to the other

Tags: android, class, kotlin, onactivityresult

Well this one is confusing me a LOT and I'm not quite sure why an error is occurring. So I'm trying to pass back data entered from two EditTextboxes from a 2nd activity back to the original one that called it.

MainActivity.kt:

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

```
var CONTACT_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST = 0

var listContacts = ArrayList<Contacts>()

val contactAdapter = DSArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, listContacts)
val listView1 = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.contact_list)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    setTitle("Contacts")

    listView1.setAdapter(contactAdapter)

    listContacts.add(Contacts("Faisal is spoiled", 732, false))
    listContacts.add(Contacts("Dawg", 666, false))
    var sortedList = listContacts.sortedWith(compareBy({it.cname}))
    listContacts.clear()
    listContacts.addAll(sortedList)
    contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    val delete_contacts = findViewById<Button>(R.id.delete_contacts)

    delete_contacts.setOnClickListener({
        var newlistContacts = ArrayList<Contacts>()
        for (x in listContacts) {
            if (x.cchecked == false) {
                newlistContacts.add(x)
            }
        }
        listContacts.clear()
        listContacts.addAll(newlistContacts)
        contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
    })

    val add_new_contact = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_contacts)

    add_new_contact.setOnClickListener {
        val intent1 = Intent(this,ContactDetails::class.java)
        startActivityForResult(intent1, CONTACT_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST)
    }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

    if (requestCode == CONTACT_DETAIL_ACTIVITY_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (data != null) {
                val n = data.getStringExtra("Name")?:"default value"
                val p = Integer.parseInt(data.getStringExtra("Phone")?:"default value")
                listContacts.add(Contacts(n, p, false))
                val sortedList = listContacts.sortedWith(compareBy({it.cname}))
                listContacts.clear()
                listContacts.addAll(sortedList)
                contactAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Now, one of the warnings I'm getting, which is for n and p, is Type Mismatch: Expected String but received String? I'm honestly not sure what that's about. Really, any help would be appreciated on this as this isn't making much sense to me

ContactDetails.kt:

```
class ContactDetails : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_details)
    setTitle("Contact Details")

    val name = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.name)
    val phone = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.phone_number)
    val add_btn = findViewById<Button>(R.id.add_person)

    add_btn.setOnClickListener {
        val n = name.getText().toString()
        val p = phone.getText().toString()

        val intent = Intent()
        intent.putExtra("Name", n)
        intent.putExtra("Phone", p)
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent)
        finish()
    }
}
}
```

I have included the activity log below:

> quote 10-11 19:36:22.777 27183-27183/com.example.contactslist E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.contactslist, PID: 27183
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactslist/com.example.contactslist.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2327)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
>        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
>           at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:5253)
>           at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:229)
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:178)
>           at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.(ArrayAdapter.java:163)
>           at com.example.contactslist.DSArrayAdapter.(DSArrayAdapter.kt:15)
>           at com.example.contactslist.MainActivity.(MainActivity.kt:22)
>           at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1067)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2317)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

Comment: `val listView1 = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.contact_list)` Put that in onCreate(). Probably the other two too.

Comment: That's what I had before and was giving me errors in my onActivity function

Comment: The variable `val listView1;` is placed outside onCreate. And assignment  `listView1 = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.contact_list)` should be in onCreate(); The rest the same. You can declare variables outside onCreate() but assign a value in onCreate();

Comment: That doesn't really change anything. My app is still crashing. My issue isn't coming from that but, rather, from how I'm exchanging data between activities

Comment: Clearly mentioned in the error< "Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.contactslist/com.example.contactslist.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate() ". Your second activity is not even created

Comment: It is created once I press the Add button. If I remove the onActivity function, I get no problems. So what do I need to do here to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warnings are because Kotlin has build in [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html)  that means that String type by itself is not null however some methonds can return a null string which is type String?. So what you need to do is supply an alternative or default value in case you get a null String.

```
data.getStringExtra("Name")?:"default value"
```

this is called an elvis operator 
you should do that for both n and p variebles since getStringExtra can return a null String

furthermore I think you are not overriding the correct method to receive the data back to the original Activity. Please try

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode:Int, resultCode:Int, data:Intent?)
```

instead of

```
fun onActivity(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent)
```

It is worth notice the

> data:Intent?

on the method I'm advising you to use. That also meand the Intent can be null but if you read [null safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html) It will teach how to deal with that in the mean time you could use something like

```
data?.let{ d -> //do stuff here inside }
```

by doing this you ensure data is not null and it's been renamed to d so inside the curly braces used as normal but call

`d.getStringExtra("Name")`

instead.

And last but not leats the other thing is giving you trouble is try to use Avtivity reference

> this

before onCreate method is finish as Md Sufi Khan point out already. I would advised you to use lazy initialization on you code like this

```
val contactAdapter = by lazy{ DSArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.activity_listview, listContacts)}
```

that means contactAdapter  will not be created right away just when need it the firts time or you can initialize inside onCreate if you so desire.

I hope that helps :)

Comment: A lot of that is very helpful, thank you. Now, unfortunately, when I try to use Intent? and override within the function definition, it gives me an error as the function isn't overriding anything and only safe or non-nullable calls are allowed for Intent? Also I can't use lazy initialization on account of the by part causing an error. Not sure what exactly I would need to do with data from your suggestion. I tried to use some of your other suggestions but it still lead to my app just crashing. I will add in my adjustments to the original post

Comment: Never mind, I'm not getting any explicit errors but my app is still crashing. I have updated all of the code as well as provided the log report

Comment: Ok glad to hear you finally figured it out  

Answer (score 0):

This error happens as you are trying to use `this` reference  before `onCreate` method being called while creating `contactAdapter` and also using `findViewById` before setting the view to the activity.

Instantiate `contactAdapter` inside `onCreate` method after `super.onCreate` call and `listView1` reference after `setContentView` call will solve your issue.

Comment: If I do that, then the onActivity function won't be able to access either the listView1 or the contactAdapter, that's why I placed it outside of the onCreate function. Doing that was also giving me errors